# YouTube's response array, sorting programmatically

Tags: java, android, youtube, youtube-api

I'm creating an app where I get a youtube search. It is currently working ok, I just want to show better results, by sorting them by title name.

I got a VideoListResponse with 50 items

```
VideoListResponse videoListResponse = null;
    try {
        videoListResponse = mYouTubeDataApi.videos()
                .list(YOUTUBE_VIDEOS_PART)
                .setFields(YOUTUBE_VIDEOS_FIELDS)
                .setKey(ApiKey.YOUTUBE_API_KEY)
                .setId(TextUtils.join(",", videoIds)).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and I want to sort them by title. Let me show an image of the item list:

[image: sort by title]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could retrieve the `List` within and sort that:

```
List<Video> items = videoListResponse.getItems();
items.sort(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getSnippet().getTitle()));
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer I end up doing it like this:
        `List<Video> items = videoListResponse.getItems();
        Collections.sort(items, new Comparator<Video>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Video video, Video t1) {
                return video.getSnippet().getTitle().compareToIgnoreCase(t1.getSnippet().getTitle());
            }
        });
        return new Pair(searchResponse.getNextPageToken(), items);`

Answer (score 2):

Well, the YouTube API already supports ordering the results by title. You won't have to do anything on your end....

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#parameters